# Flutter ProfanityFilter gives no response

Tags: flutter

I have a list of words:

```
List<String> words = ["tree","apple","car"];
```

I wanna know if the input string from a user contains a word in this list and tried the following:

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();

TextField(
controller: _controller,
onChanged: (value) =>setState(() {msg = value;}),)



final filter = ProfanityFilter.filterOnly(words);
      if(filter.hasProfanity(_controller.text)){print("Contains word from thlist");}else{print("Does not contain a word from the list");}
```

If I type "tree" nothing is printed and I don`t know why?

Comment: Where is the `filter` written?

Comment: Its a package: https://pub.dev/packages/profanity_filter

Answer (score 0):

I tried code like this and it works. Can you share whole codes or give more info please.

```
// I use List<String> because ProfanityFilter.filterOnly take List<String>
List<String> words = ["tree","apple","car"];

// I wrote to TextField which has "controller: _controller" and press the button
// This is button's onPressed method
onPressed: () {
  print('Input: ${_controller.text}');
  final filter = ProfanityFilter.filterOnly(words);
  if(filter.hasProfanity(_controller.text)) {
    print('Output: Contains');
  }else{
    print('Output: Does not contain');
  }
},
```

And this is result

```
I/flutter (20864): Input: This is my tree
I/flutter (20864): Output: Contains
I/flutter (20864): Input: tree
I/flutter (20864): Output: Contains
I/flutter (20864): Input: family-tree
I/flutter (20864): Output: Does not contain
```

Comment: Thank you! Iam using a static custom list from a seperate class and that seems to be the problem, when im using a list in the same file as the textfield is, then your exmple works for me as well. Is there a way that the input "family-tree" the word "tree" is also recognizable?